# How to get rid of escape chars

Tags: android, post, utf-8

I post a string to a database and use this method to make sure it's URL safe:

```
   public String URLsafe(String text){

    try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("URL SAFE", text+" is not URL safe");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Thing is when I retrieve the String, characters like `'` look like `/'`. Is there a way to 'decode' the String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "utf-8")`? It's the corresponding 'opposite' method to the `URLEncoder.encode` method you're using.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decode method:
[UrlDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)